# What is the best way to Inject IOptions<T> in _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I built a small web app using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, but I want to using `IOptions<T>` to pass settings from `app.json` in `_Layout`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `@inject` Razor directive to inject services into your Razor views. Of course, that also includes options. So if you have some `MyOptions` class that you have configured (e.g. using `services.Configure<MyOptions>(options => { … })` in the Startup class), then you can just inject the options into the `.cshtml`:

```
@inject IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions

<h1>@myOptions.Value.ApplicationTitle</h1>
<p>@myOptions.Value.ApplicationIntroText</p>
```

To avoid having to access `myOptions.Value` explicitly all the time, you can also use a code block and store the result in a local variable first:

```
@inject IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions
@{
    var opts = myOptions.Value;
}

<h1>@opts.ApplicationTitle</h1>
<p>@opts.ApplicationIntroText</p>
```